What film featured a man with telekenetic powers?
I saw a trailer for a film that probably came out in 2016 or 2017, but I cannot find anything about it. It is about a man who has some accident, then develops telekinesis.

The man lives in a poor neighborhood, possibly near a junkyard.
He uses his telekinetic powers to move trash around and fight people.
The main character drinks a lot and acts very recklessly.
The film is not a big-budget superhero film.

It is not Chronicle or Hancock.
Does anyone know the name of this film?

American Hero maybe? There is a junkyard scene or two, but that's not central to the plot. The rest fits though. Came out in 2015.
